# Understanding C syntax for function pointers

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

Below code is to implement vtable.

In the below code,

```
struct A;

typedef struct {
    void (*A)(struct A*);
    void (*update)(struct A*);
    int (*access)(struct A*);
} A_functable;

typedef struct A{
    int a;
    A_functable *vmt;
} A;
```

---

I could not understand mentioning `(*A)` as function pointer in `void (*A)(struct A*);` that is member in `A_functable`, where `A` is

```
  typedef struct A{
        int a;
        A_functable *vmt;
    } A;
```

---

How to understand this syntax?

Comment: Same way you read the other two function pointers, just that it's named `A`.

Comment: `A` inside `A_functable` is completely separate to the typename `A` you introduce later. To avoid confusion the author should have used different name

Comment: probably a test / homework question...

Comment: @Rafael No, it is in continuation with http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/339736/131582

Comment: Read Chapter 3 ( Unscrambling Declarations in C ) in [Expert C Programming](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/138815/Linden_-_Expert_C_Programming:_Deep_C_Secrets.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
    void (*A)(struct A*);
```

, the first `A` does not refer to `typedef struct A { ... } A` as that is only defined further below. At this point the compiler doesn't know anything about a type called `A`. `A` is simply the name of the struct member, just like `update` and `access`.

(`struct A` does refer to the struct, however: There's a `struct A;` declaration further up.)

Answer (score 0):

They are in different **namespaces**.

In C there are four different namespaces

- Tags for a struct/union/enum
- Members of struct/union (actually a separate namespace is assigned to each struct/union)
- Labels
- Ordinary identifiers.

(Section 6.1.2.3 of C90)

Identifiers in different namespaces will not clash with one other and will be referred as separate entities.

So, in your case,

- The member of the structure, `(*A)` being a function pointer is in the second namespace.
- The tags for the struct `typedef struct A` is in the first namespace,
- The struct type being an ordinary identifier is in the fourth namespace.
- Additionally, the function type for the function pointer `(*A)(struct A*)` is in the fourth namespace, being an ordinary type.

Comment: "object" means a region of storage, not an identifier.  Some objects have identifiers associated